# Combine two rows in a single row with the same ID name

Tags: sql, sql-server

Source Table with same Id need to combine them into single row

```
            +-----+-----+-----+-----+
            | Id  | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 |
            +-----+-----+-----+-----+
            | XYZ |     |   1 |   3 |
            | ZZZ |   4 |     |   5 |
            | ZZZ |     |   6 |     |
            | XYZ |   8 |     |     |
            +-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

What I want to achieve:

```
            +-----+-----+-----+-----+
            | Id  | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 |
            +-----+-----+-----+-----+
            | XYZ |   8 |   1 |   3 |
            | ZZZ |   4 |   6 |   5 |
            +-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Hint: Use `MAX`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine multiple rows into one row to replace null values in columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35611273/combine-multiple-rows-into-one-row-to-replace-null-values-in-columns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple aggregation should do the trick

**Example**

```
Select ID
      ,ID1 = max(ID1)
      ,ID2 = max(ID2)
      ,ID3 = max(ID3)
 From  YourTable
 Group By ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link -
[MySQL get first non null value after group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22782932/mysql-get-first-non-null-value-after-group-by)

```
SELECT
    id,
    MAX(id1),
    MAX(id2),
    MAX(id3)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        id, id1, id2,id3
    FROM
        Test
) AS t

GROUP BY id
```